# how to play audio in elm

Tags: api, html5-audio, elm

I am getting some data from my api.

```json
{
  "message":"",
  "data":[
    {
      "title":"Test Rock Song",
      "artist":"Music Artist Test",
      "audioUrl":"https://xyz/radio/03+-+HS3+-+Wajah+Tum+Ho+%5BDJMaza.Info%5D.mp3",
      "stateName":"California",
      "cityName":"Los Angles",
      "businessId":32
    },
    {
      "title":"R&B S1",
      "artist":"Music Artist Test",
      "audioUrl":"https://xyz/radio/1463469171175_Ba_khuda_tumhi.mp3",
      "stateName":"California",
      "cityName":"Los Angles",
      "businessId":32
    },
    {
      "title":"R&B S2",
      "artist":"Music Artist Test",
      "audioUrl":"https://xyz/radio/1465890934054_01+-+HS3+-+Tumhe+Apna+Banane+Ka+%5BDJMaza.Info%5D.mp3",
      "stateName":"California",
      "cityName":"Los Angles",
      "businessId":32
    }
  ],
  "count":3
}
```

So i have iterate that data in list, each have one mp3 url. I want when i click on link then particular mp3 will play.

Please any one help me to implement this feature.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are looking for the simplest of solutions, I would recommend rendering `<audio>` tags with the `src` attribute set to the audio URL. This can give you standard audio controls. Here is a full example along with some JSON decoders:

```elm
import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)
import Json.Decode as Json

main =
  case Json.decodeString myDecoder exampleJsonInput of
    Err err -> text err
    Ok data -> div [] <| List.map toAudioBlock data

toAudioBlock entry =  
  div []
    [ div [] [ strong [] [ text entry.title ] ]
    , div [] [ text "By: ",  text entry.artist ]
    , div [] (List.map text ["From: ",  entry.cityName, ", ", entry.stateName])
    , audio
      [ src entry.audioUrl
      , controls True
      ] []
    ]

type alias Entry =
  { title : String
  , artist : String
  , audioUrl : String
  , stateName : String
  , cityName : String
  , businessId : Int
  }

entryDecoder : Json.Decoder Entry
entryDecoder =
  Json.map6
    Entry
    (Json.field "title" Json.string)
    (Json.field "artist" Json.string)
    (Json.field "audioUrl" Json.string)
    (Json.field "stateName" Json.string)
    (Json.field "cityName" Json.string)
    (Json.field "businessId" Json.int)

myDecoder : Json.Decoder (List Entry)
myDecoder =
  Json.at ["data"] <| Json.list entryDecoder

exampleJsonInput =
  """
    {
      "message":"",
      "data":[
        {
          "title":"Test Rock Song",
          "artist":"Music Artist Test",
          "audioUrl":"https://archive.org/download/SuperMarioBros.ThemeMusic/SuperMarioBros.mp3",
          "stateName":"California",
          "cityName":"Los Angles",
          "businessId":32
        },
        {
          "title":"R&B S1",
          "artist":"Music Artist Test",
          "audioUrl":"http://216.227.134.162/ost/super-mario-bros.-1-3-anthology/pnfhmccstp/1-02-underworld.mp3",
          "stateName":"California",
          "cityName":"Los Angles",
          "businessId":32
        },
        {
          "title":"R&B S2",
          "artist":"Music Artist Test",
          "audioUrl":"https://ia800504.us.archive.org/33/items/TetrisThemeMusic/Tetris.mp3",
          "stateName":"California",
          "cityName":"Los Angles",
          "businessId":32
        }
      ],
      "count":3
    }
  """
```

You can paste this into http://elm-lang.org/try. I have substituted your audio examples with actual mp3s from the internet.

If instead you are looking for a complete audio library port to Elm, there is currently no version compatible with Elm 0.17.

Comment: Which part of the code you posted would be responsible for processing the click and starting the audio playback?

Comment: This code isn't starting or stopping audio. It just renders an html [`<audio/>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio) tag, the implementation of which varies by browser. The audio component has controls that the user can click to control audio.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, the other solutions in the thread are also good, but I think that I have a simpler example. Elm does not have a pure solution for sounds,
therefore you need use ports and some javascript, if you want to use more than the
pure html audio component.

You can find the whole example project under [Github: Elm sound by example](https://github.com/SerQuicky/elm-sound-example)

Or here the pure elm and html/javascript code.

(Main.elm)

```
port module Main exposing (..)

import Browser
import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)
import Html.Events exposing (..)



-- MAIN


main : Program () Model Msg
main =
    Browser.element
        { init = \_ -> init
        , view = view
        , update = update
        , subscriptions = \_ -> Sub.none
        }



-- PORTS


port playMusic : String -> Cmd msg


port stopMusic : String -> Cmd msg


port setSource : String -> Cmd msg



-- MODEL


type alias Model =
    { song : String
    }


init : ( Model, Cmd Msg )
init =
    ( { song = "" }
    , Cmd.none
    )



-- UPDATE


type Msg
    = Play
    | Stop
    | Set String


update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        Play ->
            ( model
            , playMusic "play"
            )

        Stop ->
            ( model
            , stopMusic "stop"
            )

        Set message ->
            ( { model | song = message }
            , setSource message
            )



-- VIEW


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div []
        [ h1 [ id "song-header" ] [ text ("Current song: " ++ model.song) ]
        , div [ Html.Attributes.class "song-holder" ]
        [ button [ onClick (Set "song1.mp3") ] [ Html.text "Song1" ]
        , button [ onClick (Set "song2.mp3") ] [ Html.text "Song2" ]
        , button [ onClick (Set "song3.wav") ] [ Html.text "Song3" ]
        ]
        , div [ Html.Attributes.class "audio-holder" ]
        [ button [ onClick Play ] [ Html.text "Play" ]
        , button [ onClick Stop ] [ Html.text "Stop" ]
        ]
    , audio [ src "./assets/sounds/song2.mp3", id "audio-player", controls True ] []
    ]
```

(javascript in index.html)

```
document.getElementById("audio-player").volume = 0.1;

app.ports.playMusic.subscribe(function() {
    document.getElementById("audio-player").play();
});

app.ports.stopMusic.subscribe(function() {
    document.getElementById("audio-player").pause();
});

app.ports.setSource.subscribe(function(source) {
    document.getElementById("audio-player").setAttribute("src",     "assets/sounds/" + source);
});
```